# What is that white spot on my goldfish?

Tags: medicines, death, goldfish, infections

[image]
Its been like a few days since it showed up, how do i treat it, 
Im tight on budget, also my red fish passed away today, and yesterdaay i bought this aquarium with filter, the capacity was 6l on old one now its 40 i think?
Edit: That was just a water reflection. [image]

Comment: first of all you need to cycle your new tank,take a look here https://www.fishlore.com/NitrogenCycle.htm i guess the pet shops think they will sell more fish if they do not inform you about this.

Comment: I don't grow plants, i use plastic ones